# Querying by property of mapped subclass in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I'm very new to NHibernate so this may be fairly trivial, but searching is leaving me confused.

I have an `AddOnAmount` table as follows:

```
AddOnID | AddOnTypeID | Period | Amount
```

where `AddOnTypeID` is a FK. The rows have a unique constraint on `AddOnTypeID` and `Period`.

The mapping looks like this:

```
<id name="Id" column="AddOnId" type="long">
    <generator class="native" />
</id>

<many-to-one name="AddOnType" column="AddOnTypeID" class="AddOnTypeStatic" not-null="true" />
<property name="Period" />      
etc.
```

The `AddOnTypeStatic` class/table just has an `Id`, which is the numerical value stored on the table, and a descriptive `Name`.

I'm trying to write a query that will search by `AddOnTypeId` and `Period`, so I can validate the existence (or not) of a row before attempting to add a duplicate from my front end, but I'm not sure how to do that as the `AddOnAmountStatic` class has a subclass whereas the table has just an Id.
So far I've written:

```
    public AddOnAmountStatic FindByAddOnTypeAndPeriod(long addOnType, string period)
    {
        return FindOne(CreateCriteria()
                           .Add(Restrictions.Eq("AddOnTypeId", addOnType))
                           .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Period", period))
                           .SetCacheable(true));
    }
```

which does not work, as `AddOnTypeId` isn't a property of `AddOnAmountStatic`. Not sure how to access the property of the subclass in this context.

My mapping works, as I've been using it so far with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem - it *was* simple but thought I'd add the solution here in case it helps anyone else.

I'd been thinking of constructing the query from the table's perspective (i.e., with the `AddOnTypeID`), whereas what I should have done is look at it from the entity's perspective. In other words, I just needed to pass in an `AddOnTypeStatic` object.

What I did was take my `AddOnTypeID` parameter, check *it* exists through NHibernate (returning either an `AddOnTypeStatic` object or null) then passed that through to the original query. Final query is simply

```
return FindOne(CreateCriteria()
              .Add(Restrictions.Eq("AddOnType", addOnType))
              .(Restrictions.Eq("Period", period))
              .SetCacheable(true));
```

Hope this helps another newbie!